# Kotlin flatMapMerge inconsistent when combining same flow multiple times

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I have an app that `flatMapMerge`s a shared flow A to create a flow B. I then combine Flow A with Flow B to get a final result that I `collectLatest`. Sometimes it outputs all the results. However, for other times, it skips some of the output. Here's a simplified example:

```
val flowA = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(replay = Int.MAX_VALUE)
val flowB = flowA.flatMapMerge {
    // In the real app, this flow is created in a complex way
    flow {
        emit(it + 2)
        emit(it + 3)
        emit(it + 4)
        emit(it + 5)
        emit(it + 6)
        emit(it + 7)
        emit(it + 8)
        emit(it + 9)
    }
}
flowA.emit(1)
flowA.combine(flowB, ::Pair).collect { (a, b) ->
    // I need access to the value of flowA for calculations here
    Log.d(TAG, "result A: $a, B: $b")
}
```

1st run:

```
result A: 1, B: 3
result A: 1, B: 5
result A: 1, B: 7
result A: 1, B: 9
result A: 1, B: 10
```

2nd run:

```
result A: 1, B: 3
result A: 1, B: 5
result A: 1, B: 7
result A: 1, B: 8
result A: 1, B: 10
```

Expected output:

```
result A: 1, B: 3
result A: 1, B: 4
result A: 1, B: 5
result A: 1, B: 6
result A: 1, B: 7
result A: 1, B: 8
result A: 1, B: 9
result A: 1, B: 10
```

I also tried adjusting the replay, but it has no effect. I also tried `collectLatest` instead of `collect`, but also no change.

Should I be using something other than `flatMapMerge`? I tried `flatMapLatest`, but that only outputs the first and the last result. Should the `MutableSharedFlow` be something else?

**How do I get all the results to output every time?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is with combine function

as of [official documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html), **combine** function:

> Returns a Flow whose values are generated with transform function by
> combining **the most recently emitted** values by each flow.

If transform function of `combine()` has some heavy calculation inside it, it is possible that combine() doesn't emit all results.

So for obtaining all results, the below strategy works fine.

```kotlin
val flowA = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
        .onStart { emit(1) }

    val flowB = flowA.flatMapMerge {
        flow {
            for (i in 2..9) {
                emit(Pair(it, i))
            }
        }
    }

    runBlocking {
        flowB.collect { (a, b) ->
            println("result A: $a, B: $b")

        }
    }
```

Output:

```
result A: 1, B: 3
result A: 1, B: 4
result A: 1, B: 5
result A: 1, B: 6
result A: 1, B: 7
result A: 1, B: 8
result A: 1, B: 9
result A: 1, B: 10
```